# Проблема с парсингом картинок

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Проблема с парсингом картинок заключается в том что картинки не вытаскиваются нормально, при попытке запуска кода выдается ошибка `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`
но следует только убрать строку которая должна собирать картинки то код начинает нормально работать

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://rimax-industry.en.alibaba.com/productlist-1.html'
LINK = 'https://rimax-industry.en.alibaba.com/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/92.0.4515.131'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='icbu-product-card vertical large product-item')
    items = items + soup.find_all('div', class_='icbu-product-card vertical large product-item last')
    disks = []

    for item in items:
        disks.append(
            {
                'title': item.find('div', class_='title').get_text(),
                'link_prod': LINK + item.find('a', class_='product-image').get('href'),
                'minitems': item.find('span', class_='value').get_text(),
                'price': item.find('span', class_='num').get_text(),
                'img_product': item.find('a', class_='product-image').find('img').get('src')
            }
        )
    return disks


html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Но следует оставить строку со сбором картинок и заменить

```
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='icbu-product-card vertical large product-item')
 items = items + soup.find_all('div', class_='icbu-product-card vertical large product-item last')
```

на

```
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='component-product-list')
```

то есть просто повысить иерархию классов то получается получить все указанные данные но только по одному товару

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что в указанной строке, происходит поиск тега 'img' и 'product-image' и очевидно не найдя оного, бс4 возвращает тип none. К которому происходит обращение, как будто это действительный тег.
Вероятно замена поможет

```
img_product=item.find('a', class_='product-image').find('img')
if img_product is bs.element.Tag:
 'all ok'
 img_product.get('src')
else:
 'no result'
```